# SAPUI5 Get context/model property for smarttable row

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

i have a smart table where i add some tooltip for an Icon. In my table i display COL1 COL2 and COL3, moreover COL4 and COL5 is not visible (but still in the model - OData is generated by CDS View). Now, for a line i try to get the property which is not visible in the table:

```
            var oContext = oItem.getBindingContext();
            var oLine = oContext.getObject(oContext.getPath());
```

oLine object contains only COL1 COL2 and COL3 properties, no acces to COL4 and COL5. Is there any chance to fetch then ? I guess the data is somehow buffered already, isn't it ?

Comment: why do you pass "oContext.getPath()" to the "getObject" call? Is there such properties in the "getObject()" call without arguments?

Comment: Even though if you do getObject you will get only the visible columns not the hidden ones from the SmartTable.

Comment: what do you mean by "hidden" ? Those ones that can be added via personalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`requestAtLeastFields` property](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable%23methods/getRequestAtLeastFields) of a SmartTable control.